# How to hide interface methods in the web service when using @WebService's `endpointInterface` attribute?

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

Is there a way to prevent a method from an interface used in `@WebService`'s `endpointInterface` attribute to be exposed in the web service? I'm using the endpointInterface as that seems to be the only way to make the service work on JBoss with Metro, not doing so results in a:

`javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried annotating the methods you don't want to be exposed as `@WebMethod(exclude = true)`?

Comment: Yes, but even those not annotated are exposed.